# AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'to_snake_case'

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, ubuntu, keras

I'm trying a small program to capture emotion from an image from [here](https://analyticsindiamag.com/face-emotion-recognizer-in-6-lines-of-code/https://)
**error**

```
LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS[generic_utils.to_snake_case(key)] = value
AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'to_snake_case'
```

**Code.py**

```
from fer import FER
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_snake_case

def emotionCapture():
    img = plt.imread("happy.jpg")
    detector = FER(mtcnn=True)
    print(detector.detect_emotions(img))
    plt.imshow(img)

    predicted_emotion, score = detector.top_emotion(img)
    print (predicted_emotion)
    return predicted_emotion

emotionCapture()
```

**Keras** version 2.4.3
**Tensorflow** version 2.5.0
**opencv-python** version 4.5.2.52

Answer (score 0):

After removing `'mtcnn=True'` from  `detector = FER(mtcnn=True)` the function worked.